# Quicklfix related question(FIX::Application)

Tags: visual-c++, quickfix

I am trying to use FIX::Application along with SessionSettings.
The Fix server I am trying to connect to does not see  any incoming connection. From my side I see a Logon Message being formulated in toAdmin() callback(which I print out and add certain fields to. 
The Question is 
1. Do I need to call some form of sendTarget in toAdmin?(I tried that but get a Session not found error)
2. Is there anyway I can increase logging(start logging whats going on under the hood).
Thanks

Comment: I seem to have found part of the awnser. It would appear sendToTarget need not be invoked from the toAdmin callback. But I am still stuck on how to proceed any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the sendTOTarget need not be called in the toAdmin.
As far as logging goes, what i hear is passing th in FIX::LogFactory should be enough.